# Using MailMessage To View Email

Tags: c#, wpf

Is there any way to view an email using MailMessage rather than sending the message. I am using SmtpClient to send the messages but in some cases the email needs to be reviewed and then manually sent by the user.

Comment: In some cases, or in all cases? What's the context in which the email is being sent - appropriate solution could be different depending upon this.

Comment: You have to use some other technique to review your email before sending, i dnt think mailmessage used for this. It is an object used to send email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no builtin method in **SmtpClient** class to review the email. You have to manually review the message.

Before sending you have to review the email manully.

You can use [**WebBrowser**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) object to view the body part of the email to see how receiver will see the email.

Other reviewing also have to done manually.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to save it as a MIME message (`.eml`) to a temporary file, and then launch it using your registered message viewer (such as Windows Live Mail or Thunderbird).

To save the `MailMessage` to file, you could use the `Save` extension method provided in this Code Project article: [Adding Save() functionality to Microsoft.Net.Mail.MailMessage](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32434/Adding-Save-functionality-to-Microsoft-Net-Mail-Ma).

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage
{
    Subject = "Test",
    Body = "Hello world",
    From = new MailAddress("sender@abc.com"),
};
message.To.Add(new MailAddress("email@domain.com"));

string tempEmlPath = Path.Combine(
    Path.GetTempPath(), 
    Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".eml");

message.Save(tempEmlPath);

Process.Start(tempEmlPath);
```